# PDF renders as empty white box

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, pdf, path, render

I have a project named "Project", and a PDF file caled "file.pdf" located in `Project/app/assets/file.pdf`. I want to render the PDF on a page called "file.html", located in `Project/app/views/static/file.html`.

I wrote the following code, but all that displays is an empty white box.

```
<embed src="../../assets/file.pdf" width="500" height="375" type='application/pdf'>
```

I'm pretty sure my browser can't find the file. What could I be doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** I also tried it with an image, placed in `app/assets/images/Image.png`, like so:

```
<embed src="../../assets/images/Image.png" width="500" height="375" type='image/png'>
```

but that doesn't render either.

**UPDATE 2:** Output from console:

Started GET "/file" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-02-21 04:48:27 -0600
Processing by StaticController#file as HTML

Rendered static/file.html.erb within layouts/application (63.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 757ms (Views: 749.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Started GET "/assets/application.self-e570ac372b74f676a029186250aeeba9bf7016bcd014314d103b5d18b3eb858e.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-02-21 04:48:28 -0600

Started GET "/assets/pdf-8f705790d319666d8f804cf8809f4d74f036483049ef8c520646d6c98ebedc5f.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-02-21 04:48:28 -0600

Started GET "/assets/Advanced_Reading_Sample.pdf" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-02-21 04:48:28 -0600

Comment: What browser are you using? I have the exact setup and using chrome I am able to render the pdf doc.

Comment: @NormanBentley I'm using the latest version of Chrome on Ubuntu.

Comment: strange, I am on windows and dont have an Ubuntu VM available.  How about if you put them in the same folder and update the src?  to just src="file.pdf"

Comment: @NormanBentley That gives the same result.

Comment: Your code looks correct, try embedding another pdf, or an image.

Comment: @NormanBentley No other pdf or image works, either.

Comment: Rendering an image with "application/pdf" doesn't seem like a good idea...

Comment: @DavidvanDriessche Why not?

Comment: You're giving the browser an image and telling it it's a PDF file.

Comment: The media type for PNG files is "image/png". If you specifically tell the browser you're giving it a PDF file, and then you put a PNG file there, that isn't going to help you figure out a situation that already isn't working in the first place, is it?

Comment: @DavidvanDriessche Oh of course. I changed it but it still won't render.

Comment: Is your `Project` a rails application?

Comment: @FixerRB Yes, it is.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14081128/how-can-i-embed-a-pdf-viewer-in-a-web-page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244788/embed-vs-object

Comment: Are you running your app in production mode? Because in production mode rails deactivates serving of static assets (from `app/assets`); or, if you're not running that way, maybe that setting is disabled: check for `config.serve_static_files` [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html).

Comment: @FerGarcía No, I'm running it in development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have no idea why my app can't find the file. I just ended up using iframes and the absolute url of the file:

```
<iframe src="http://www.project.com/file.pdf" style="width:100%;height:100%;"><p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p></iframe>
```

And finally, the file renders.

Answer (score 4):

In your controller write,

```
def file
  pdf_filename = File.join(Rails.root, "/assets/file.pdf")
  send_file(pdf_filename, :filename => pdf_filename, :disposition => 'inline', :type => "application/pdf")
end
```

Rename your file.html => file.html.erb and place it under views/controller_name/file.html.erb, also add route to this controller action.

In above setup when you access controller/file/ pdf will shown in the browser(inline).

Answer (score 2):

Try this and see if it works

```
<iframe src="yourfile.pdf" style="width:100%; height:700px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: I'm getting a screen that tells me there are no route matches for that path.

Comment: do you see this part  `src="yourfile.pdf"` have you tried to link that part to where your pdf is? e.g. `src="../../assets/file.pdf"` .Try linking that to your file . And if your file is a pdf it has to display.

Comment: I tried that as well, but it's still telling me it can't find the route.

Comment: @JoeMorano check your file it must be pdf or you path might be incorrect, 
 i.e. `src="../../assets/file.pdf"` that path might not be pointing to that file or file might be corrupt leading to white screen. If it doesnt work we can try another way

Comment: @JoeMorano What if you copy the pdf to the same folder where the `file.html` file is the try this direct path  `src="file.pdf" ` just try. here where i am it is working .

Comment: They're in the exact same folder and and I wrote src="file.pdf", but I'm getting the error 'No route matches [GET] "/file.pdf"'

Comment: @JoeMorano try the same with another file e.g. `src="anotherfile.pdf"`  to test if the file is corrupt. and if you have php codes in that page then save the page as `file.php` insted as `file.html`

Answer (score 1):

Create folder called `pdf` (for example) in `app/assets` and put there your `file.pdf` then in `app/views/static/file.html` change `src` of `embed` tag to `/assets/file.pdf`. This should do the trick.

Comment: I tried that, but it just shows the same empty white box.

Comment: @JoeMorano oops, there should be `/assets/file.pdf` in `src` instead of `/assets/pdf/file.pdf`.

Comment: Yeah I'm still getting the the same result.

Comment: @JoeMorano have you tried to restart rails server? If it doesn't help can you post here your console log?

Comment: Yes, I restarted the server. What console log should I post?

Comment: @JoeMorano that one which appears in console when you run `rails server`. Try to reload your page where pdf should  appear and then post the log here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104087/discussion-between-fixerrb-and-joe-morano).

Answer (score 1):

Try, This will help

```
<a href="../../assets/file.pdf" target="_blank">Click To View</a>
```

thanks

[Mark SykOv](http://www.marksykov.com/)