# Send pdf from python(pyramid) to jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jinja2, pyramid

how to send PDF file that can be rendered to jinja2??
write both codes (.py) and (.js) if possible. 
here is my ajax code

```
$("#print").click(function(event) {
$.ajax(
  {
    type: "POST",
    url: "/printledgerreport",
    global: false,
    async: false,
    dataType : 'json',
    //contentType : 'application/pdf'

    data: {"backflag":0,"accountcode":$("#accountcode").val(),"calculatefrom":$("#calculatefrom").val(), "calculateto":$("#calculateto").val(),"financialstart":sessionStorage.yyyymmddyear1,"projectcode":$("#projectcode").val(),"monthlyflag":false,"narrationflag":false},
    beforeSend: function(xhr)
    {
      xhr.setRequestHeader('gktoken',sessionStorage.gktoken );
    },
    success: function(data){
      window.open("ledgerReport.pdf");
    }
  });
});
```

please tell me how to write pyramid code

Now here is my new pyramid code:

```
@view_config(route_name="printledgerreport", renderer="")
def printLedgerReport(request):    
    filepath = ("ledgerReport.pdf")
    response = FileResponse(filepath)
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = ("attachment;             filename=ledgerReport.pdf")
    return response
```

Comment: This question needs more input and clarification; in its current format readers cannot understand the issue the author haves.

Comment: This is my new code please check and tell me how to open pdf file from ajax

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  I'm on my 5th margarita. It should work.  :)  Remember to add route for "download_PDF".

```
@view_config(route_name="download_PDF", renderer="")
 def download_view(request):
     filepath = ("pathtomyfile/test.pdf")
     response = FileResponse(filepath)
     response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = ("attachment; filename=test.pdf")
     return response
```

Whoops. This just downloads the file. Maybe you can make it work with jinja. Again. too many margaritas: )

Comment: Can you please write the ajax code for same which whill open that pdf file

Comment: Can you please write  ajax code for the same which will open that pdf file
its really urgent my pdf file is not received at js
And also, I want to send some data to python file and then send back response as a pdf

Comment: It sounds like you want to embed a PDF file in your html,  correct?  Look at this answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14081128/how-can-i-embed-a-pdf-viewer-in-a-web-page

Comment: No I dont find that pdf recieved

Comment: Sry.  You will have to make your question more clear.

Comment: where this response is gone??
who will catch it and then open that file by window.open()

Comment: Maybe this will help.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34586671/download-pdf-file-using-jquery-ajax