# Java - Send OutputStream to printer directly from servlet/Controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, itext, printstream

Using my spring controller I want to directly open the printing view of generated pdf.By now I am generating a pdf using iTextPDF and put it to the OutputStream (HttpServletResponse.getOutputStream()).It is downloading the pdf. I can open it in browser and print using print button.
What I want is getting the print UI from the controller or without print UI send to the printer.
I have added some of my controller method,

```
 String mimeType = "application/pdf";
 System.out.println("MIME type: " + mimeType);
 response.setContentType(mimeType);
 String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
 String headerValue = String.format("theCoder379.PDF");
 response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);
 OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
 createPdf(outStream, theObject);
 outStream.close();
```

In createPdf(outStream, theObject) method it is adding the generated iText pdf using 'theObject' to the 'outStream'.
How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible the way you want (from the server side).

> By now I am generating a pdf using iTextPDF and put it to the OutputStream

Good. That's effectively all you can do from the server side code.

> I can open it in browser and print using print button
>   The browser loads an external application (pdf plugin/viewer) and let the plugin display the file you've generated. You have no control over it whatsoever.

However you may create your own page with [embedded plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14081128/how-can-i-embed-a-pdf-viewer-in-a-web-page).

```
<object data="./pdfServlet" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
 <p>Alternative text - include a link <a href="myfile.pdf">to the PDF!</a>
 </p>
</object>
```

and try to invoke the *[print](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_print.asp)* event in the client-side javascript.

```
window.print();
```

However - I see some potential issues

- it may not work on all browsers and all version you may want
- some people (myself included) are sensitive if a web page tries to do thing the are not explicitly asked for (such as printing)