# Storing pdf in a blob column into database table , pdf preview in apex form/region?

Tags: oracle, pdf, oracle-apex, preview

I'm using oracle apex 5.1 and I'm storing a pdf into a blob column into a database table; I would like to extract that blob column into apex and be able to preview it on a apex form/ region. I know you can download a pdf, but I just want to preview without having to download in pdf format. Would you somehow try to store the blob content into APEX_APPLICATION_TEMP_FILES for displaying purposes?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure copying the blob to a built-in APEX table would make this any easier.

But I think this should be feasible. There are two parts you need to work out: (a) turning the blob into a URL that you can use to download or view the PDF directly, and (b) embedding the PDF on an APEX page using that URL.

For the first part, see [this excellent post for an example](https://joelkallman.blogspot.com/2014/03/yet-another-post-how-to-link-to.html) of how to generate a download link for a blob in APEX. There are a ton of other solutions out there, but this one is very clean and easy to use.

For the second part, see [this question about how to embed a PDF in a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14081128/how-can-i-embed-a-pdf-viewer-in-a-web-page), or [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html). Whether you want to go with `<object>`/`<embed>` tags or a JavaScript library will probably depend on your environment and what browsers you want to support.