# Is there an alternative to using an iFrame to view PDFs in Shiny?

Tags: r, iframe, shiny

I would rather not use an iFrame to view web hosted PDFs in my Shiny application if I can at all avoid it. It is bad practice for my particular project. Are there alternatives for viewing hosted PDFs in R Shiny?

EDIT: By hosted, I mean stored in a file storage service, such as AWS S3 or Azure Blob

Comment: By "hosted" PDF, you mean the PDF is on a website?

Comment: I mean stored in a cloud service like AWS S3 or Azure Blob

Comment: Would it there any problem to download it with the shiny app?

Answer (score -1):

You could try to use the HTML-function to include HTML-Code in your shiny project.

```
tags$div(
  HTML("HTML-Code")
)
```

There seem to be other ways of showing PDFs in HTML, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14081128/how-to-embed-a-pdf-viewer-in-a-page)

Comment: Can you provide a working example of implementing PDF.js into a Shiny app?