# How to render pdf content in react.js app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf

I have a specific use case where I have to fetch the pdf content using `axios.get` and then render the content explicitly on UI

On front end I am using React.js and having Express.js server in backend.

My front end React app cannot call cross domain apis (third party apis) so, I have created an endpoint on backend express server which is running on the same domain that eventually deals with third apis, basically fetch pdf content from any third party links.

```
router.get('/fetch-pdf-content', async (req, res) => {
try {
    const { data } = await axios.get('https://abc.pdf');
    res.contentType('application/pdf');
    res.send(data);
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).send(error.code);
}

})
```

On front end, how I can render the `data` I get from server endpoint ?

I tried using object tag on front end like

```
<object data={'http://localhost:5000/fetch-pdf-content'} type="application/pdf">
<p>Alternative text</p>
</object>
```

but it does not work. I am able to see object tag in the document but with empty document and `Alternative text` is not getting displayed.

Comment: See what happens if you add `type="application/pdf"` as an attribute on the object. Also this answer may help solve your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14081168/621827

Comment: thanks @Stephen Gilboy, it still does not work

Comment: if i fire `http://localhost:500/fetch-pdf-content` explicitly on browser then pdf pages are shown with empty content. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

[Axios uses the `responseType: 'json'` by default](https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config), therefore some bytes are
interpreted in the wrong way and converted to different values, and the binary data becomes invalid.

E.g. a byte value like `231` is converted to `65533`, which is the [*replacement character* "�"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)).

You need to [set `responseType: 'arraybuffer'`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType):

```
const { data } = await axios.get( url, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' } );
```